# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (in create react app: App.js)

Tags: javascript, typeerror, create-react-app

I've built a form using create-react-app, and when I run 'npm start' in the project directory, the browser opens a new tab, localhost:3000 and I get the error above. I'll provide the error immediately below, and the contents of my App.js file at the bottom. Please let me know if more information is required, thank you!

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        App
        src/App.js:83
          80 | <fieldset disabled={submitting}>
          81 |   <label>
          82 |     <p>Name</p>
        > 83 |     <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.name}/>
             | ^  84 |     <p>Email</p>
          85 |     <input name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.email}/>
          86 |     <p>Phone (recommended)</p>
```

I've built a form using create-react-app, and when I run 'npm start' in the project directory, the browser opens a new tab, localhost:3000 and I get the error above. I'll provide the contents of my App.js file below. Please let me know if more information is required, thank you!

```
// import React and use hooks to create objects
// hooks let you use state without writing a class
import React, { useReducer, useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

// reducer function that takes inputs state and event
const formReducer = (state, event) => {
  // when the event.reset property is true
  // reset the field values to empty strings
  if(event.reset) {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      phone: '',
      type: '',
      'contact': false
    }
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    // pass an event object with properties name and value
    [event.name]: event.value
  }
}

function App() {
  // variables formData and setFormData are assigned to:
  // the hook useReducer called with the parameter formReducer
  const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer);
  // variables submitting and setSubmitting are assigned to the result of:
  // calling the useState hook with a parameter of false
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  // function handleSubmit has parameter event
  const handleSubmit = event => {
  // run the event.preventDefault property in this function
    event.preventDefault();
  // set the setSubmitting variable to true
    setSubmitting(true);
  // show Submitting Form message for 3 sec on button click
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitting(false);
      setFormData({
        reset: true
      })
    }, 3000)
  }
// function to pull the data from the event.target
// and pass the object to setFormData
  const handleChange = event => {
    // check if event.target.type is checkbox
    const isCheckbox = event.target.type === 'checkbox';
    // setFormData is an object with keys: name and value
    // and values of event.target.name and event.target.value
    setFormData({
      name: event.target.name,
      // if type is checkbox, pass event.target.checked as the value
      // otherwise, pass event.target.value as value
      value: isCheckbox ? event.target.checked : event.target.value
    });
  }
// the user-facing section
// update the onChange event handler to use the handleChange function
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Get help with your VA Claim</h1>
      <h2>Let's increase your VA rating</h2>
      {submitting &&
      <div>
        You are submitting the following:
        <ul>
          {Object.entries(formData).map(([name, value]) => (
            <li key={name}><strong>{name}</strong>:{value.toString()}</li>
          ))}
          </ul>
      </div>
      }

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <fieldset disabled={submitting}>
        <label>
          <p>Name</p>
          <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.name}/>
          <p>Email</p>
          <input name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.email}/>
          <p>Phone (recommended)</p>
          <input name="phone" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.phone}/>
        </label>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset disabled={submitting}>
        <label>
          <p>Please choose an option:</p>
          <select name="type" onChange={handleChange} value={formData.type}>
            <option value="VA Claim">VA Claim</option>
            <option value="VA Appeal">VA Appeal</option>
            <option value="Not sure">I'm not sure</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <label>
          <p>Contact me about my VA Claim/Appeal.</p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="contact" onChange={handleChange} checked={formData['contact']} />
        </label>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to pass a second argument to useReducer that is the initial state. For example:

```
// variables formData and setFormData are assigned to:
  // the hook useReducer called with the parameter formReducer
  const [formData, setFormData] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    type: '',
    'contact': false
  });
```

Without the initial state, React gives me an error that the input was going from uncontrolled to controlled, presumably because there was no initial value so it was undefined.

I also changed the map line to remove the square brackets, but I'm not sure that was necessary, just thought I'd mention it incase it helps:

```
{Object.entries(formData).map((name, value) => (
```

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you're saying to pass a second argument to useReducer, the second argument being an object containing the initial state of all the form fields? I will try it!

Comment: Yes, that's right. const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialArg);

Comment: Thank you digibake!! Your solution worked, and solved my problem! Much appreciated!!